# Integrating a video streaming in tkinter frame

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter

I am doing a project where I decided to split the main window in two frames using `grid`. Where the left frame takes 85% of the screen and 15% goes to right frame. My target is that I want to add a live video stream on the left frame. The problem I am facing is that whenever I start the stream, it takes up the whole window. However, I want to keep the stream on the left without affecting the frame of the right side.

I am following a OOP concepts for better management. where each frame belongs to a class. I have another class which contains the whole window and two classes that holds two frames. My idea was that if I add anything in one particular class(frame) and I pass the master as self.frame, it would only stay in that frame. However, while it was the case for simple buttons, it has not working properly with video streaming. I am aware of resizing the video to fit in the frame but for some reason it keeps taking up the whole space.

```
 def show_webcam(self):
      if self.capture is None:
         self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture("URL")

        # Assuming first frame's size represents the feed's resolution.
         ret, frame = self.capture.read()
         if ret:
            height, width, channels = frame.shape
            self.aspect_ratio = width / height

      last_frame_width = None

      # FPS counting initializations
      start_time = time.time()
      frame_count = 0

      while True:
        ret, frame = self.capture.read()
        if not ret:
            break

        frame_count += 1  # Increment frame count

        frame_width = self.frame.winfo_width()

        # Resize only if frame width has changed
        if last_frame_width != frame_width:
            frame_height = int(frame_width / self.aspect_ratio)
            frame = cv2.resize(frame, (frame_width, frame_height))
            last_frame_width = frame_width

        cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=Image.fromarray(cv2image))

        if self.video_label is not None:
            self.video_label.configure(image=photo)
            self.video_label.image = photo
        else:
            self.video_label = tk.Label(self.frame, image=photo)
            self.video_label.pack()

        elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
        if elapsed_time > 1.:  # Every second
            fps = frame_count / elapsed_time
            print(f"FPS: {fps:.2f}")  # Print FPS to the console
            frame_count = 0
            start_time = time.time()

        #time.sleep(0.01)

      if self.capture is not None:
           self.capture.release()
      cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Why do you have `cv2.destroyAllWindows()`? Also a `while True` loop isn't good practice with `tkinter`. Please look at some `tkinter` tutorials